# Laravel 4 hasMany with WHERE clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Not sure if this is the correct way to add an additional query to the hasMany argument but was unsuccessful. Is this possible?

```
public function menuItems($parent=false){
    if($parent){
        $menuItems = $this->hasMany('MenuItem')->where('parent',$parent);
    }else{
        $menuItems = $this->hasMany('MenuItem');
    }
    return $menuItems;
}
```

When called using

```
$menu_items = $menu->menuItems(0);
```

This just seems to return an empty array when passed a parent. Even though data with MenuItem->parent = 0 exists

Do I need to some way distinguish I'm asking for my linked items "parent" and not the main models "parent"

Comment: Can you post your table layout? I'm not able to tell what's going on here.. Your child table should only have one reference to the parent row.. Your `->hasMany()` from CHILD to PARENT is what references it. You may need to supply the second argument defining the parent-child relationship key.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
public function menuItems(){
        return $this->hasMany('MenuItem');
}
```

Called with

```
$menu_items = $menu->menuItems()->where('parent', 0)->get();
```

Comment: As far as I know $menu->menuItems() returns a HasMany instance. Can't find the where() method in the HasMany class or it's parents though. Anyone knows which where() method is called? I'm curious since PHPStorm gives a warning that the where method doesn't exist.

Comment: In Laravel 5, attaching where clause directly in relationships works as well:     
    return $this->hasMany('MenuItem')->where('parent', $parent)->get();

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the query part but at first wouldn't passing a 0 to the function still register the $parent variable as false?  So maybe just check if the $parent is not null.

```
public function menuItems($parent = null){
    if(!$parent == null)){
        $menuItems = $this->hasMany('MenuItem')->where('parent',$parent);
    }else{
        $menuItems = $this->hasMany('MenuItem');
    }
    return $menuItems;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In PHP `0 = FALSE`, change this

```
if( $parent ){
```

for this

```
if( $parent !== false ){
```